# Android: Get frame from network video resource

Tags: android

I want to get a pointed frame from network video by MediaMetadataRetriever. But when I called MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(myUrl), app will crash becauseof IllegalArgumentException. Is there anyone has this problem and could you tell me how to deal with it? Thanks a lot!

```
MediaMetadataRetriever rev = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
rev.setDataSource(myUrl); //will crash at here
Bitmap bitmap = rev.getFrameAtTime(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() * 1000,
            MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC)
```

Comment: It is not support network resource, so you get the crash.

Comment: Oh, got it! So do you have any advise to get frame from network resource?

Comment: If you want to get frame image of network media streaming, maybe FFMPEG could help you, ask google how to merge it into android system.

Comment: Actually, I tried to use TextureView to play video and get frame. But when I launched demo app on my AndroidTV, TextureView cannot normally work. There is only audio without image. And some devices can display and some cannot. I don't know why, do you have use it?